# Joomla web form feed into Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, joomla, webforms, sharepoint-workflow

The organization I work for has a Joomla intranet page with many web forms.  We recently licensed sharepoint online. I would like to have some of the Joomla web forms to feed into sharepoint.

The current workflow looks like this...using computer add move change form as an example:
Currently users fills out the web form on the intranet, it will send me an email.  I will review the request,  then I will contact the requesters manager and verify the request (make sure that the person needs a new laptop or be moved to the corner office). Once the request is approved I will forward the information to the correct team or teams.

What I would like is to have the form information to flow in sharepoint.  I would like to use the built in document approval in sharepoint.  This is one of the main problem with the current system is having to track down the managers for each department (they are never in the office, or change from month to month)  Once it is approved it will forward to me.

The web form work great right now and I dont want to fix something that is not broken. Not all users have accounts with sharepoint mainly only supervisors...and we unfortunately have a bandwidth cap....so setting up all the forms again in sharepoint with anonymous access would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint's web services to add new items to a list.  In my experience the hardest part of doing this is passing the credentials to SharePoint, but once you have that figured out, you can use the UpdateListItems service to add new items to a List.

For example, you can create a new item by creating a batch xml node

```
$xml = '<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" ViewName="270C0508-A54F-4387-8AD0-49686D685EB2">';
$xml .= '<Method ID="1" Cmd="New">';
$xml .= '<Field Name="ID">New</Field>';
$xml .= '<Field Name="Title">Value</Field>';
$xml .= '<Field Name="Date_Column">2007-3-25</Field>';
$xml .= '<Field Name="Date_Time_Column">2006-1-11T09:15:30Z</Field>';
$xml .= '</Method>';
$xml .= '</Batch>';
```

Then wrap that into the soap envelope

```
$soap = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">';
$soap .= '<soapenv:Header/>';
$soap .= '<soapenv:Body>';
$soap .= '<soap:UpdateListItems>';
$soap .= '<soap:listName>yourlistname</soap:listName>';
$soap .= '<soap:updates>';
$soap .= $xml;
$soap .= '</soap:updates>';
$soap .= '</soap:UpdateListItems>';
$soap .= '</soapenv:Body>';
$soap .= '</soapenv:Envelope>';
```

Substitute your listname and viewname in the code above and send it off to the SharePoint server using a soap client or curl.

For the complete documentation, see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx